# Re-using existing browser tabs when starting a new process

Tags: browser, automation

Right now I'm using Process.Start(URL_Here) to open a new page in the web browser - it will either open a browser or a new tab if one is already running. I was wondering, is there any reasonable (i.e. the one which won't require any 'hacks') way to re-use already opened tabs? - by "re-use" I mean a situation when f.e. www.google.com is already opened, I want to open a google page again, but instead of opening a new google tab it will redirect to the one that is already opened. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like standard browser behavior, and it's unlikely you'll be able to change it with simple command line arguments.

If you're willing to use Chrome and give every piece of data you transmit to The Company of Great Evil, then [here's a plugin](https://github.com/mbhutton/chrome-duplicate-tab-detector) that can reuse a tab if you're using the same URL.